# Block direct haproxy ip

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I have a haproxy config like this:

```
global
   log /dev/log local0
   log /dev/log local1 notice
   chroot /var/lib/haproxy
   stats timeout 30s
   user haproxy
   group haproxy
   daemon
   maxconn 5000

defaults
   log global
   mode tcp
   option tcplog
   option dontlognull
   timeout connect 10000
   timeout client 300000
   timeout server 300000

frontend http_front
   bind *:80
   bind *:443
   default_backend http_back

frontend port80-redirect
   mode http
   bind LOCAL-VPS-IP:80
   redirect scheme https

backend http_back
   balance roundrobin
   option ssl-hello-chk
   server SERVERNAME MYMAINVPS-IP:443 send-proxy-v2 check maxconn 5000

listen stats
   bind *:8181
   mode http
   stats enable
   stats uri /
   stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
   stats auth ADMIN:PASS
```

Everything works well. There are some cases, people can my find and access directly my HAPROXY-VPS-IP. How to config to block access directly to my HAPROXY-VPS-IP? Ie.

Normally:

- domain => cloudflare => haproxy-vps-ip => main vps

Direct access: (I want to block this intention)

- haproxy-vps-ip = > main vps

Thanks you.